# Is the [job-hunting] tag really needed anymore?

Tags: discussion, jobs, tag-block-request

I searched through Meta to see if this had been discussed, and with no returns that were relevant, here we go.

To cut to the chase, it seems that the tag [job-hunting](/questions/tagged/job-hunting) should be removed. Questions I see with this tag are usually off-topic or should be sent to Programmers SE. The [job-hunting](/questions/tagged/job-hunting) list contains tons of closed questions, and, well... there's careers.stackexchange.com. Seems like there's no need for this tag to exist, at least that I can see.

Comment: Hmm. That's a perfectly valid and correct tag for these completely off-topic questions. Not sure I support wholesale removal, unless the questions themselves were deleted.

Comment: Can we simply blacklist it for new questions?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I'd assume they were just closed since I was able to view them. I d wonder though that if someone that came here with that question in mind saw that it was a valid tag, it would validate that those type of questions were valid to ask on SO? Dont' know how many question askers think that way though.

Comment: No, what I mean is I don't support deleting the tag unless we delete the questions themselves at the same time.  Paŭlo's suggestion is better, though.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta It would be a good preventative measure from having the amount increase at the very least.

Comment: I just doled out 30+ close votes, can somebody please join? Most of these don't belong anywhere. Some are really good and could find a home on Programmers.

Comment: See also `[jobs]`, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in favor of closing/deleting the questions with this tag.

However, **they should not be migrated to Programmers** in a wholesale fashion.  Remember that Programmers is about questions which apply to all programmers, not to all careers.  See [this  post on Meta.Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster/590#590).

Take a look at the status of the [[job-hunting]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job-hunting) tag there; 8/25 questions are closed.  If any of the PSE people want these questions, they should go through the tag on SO and flag for migration.

Tag blacklists are usually used because the tag is bad, not because questions which use the tag are off-topic.  After this tag is cleaned up, we should then wait and see if we get new questions - Are the existing warnings about on-topic questions sufficient to stop people asking job-hunting questions?   If not, I suppose a case could be made to blacklist the tag. But we're not there yet.

Comment: Programmers also has [job-searching] and a bunch of job-hunting questions hiding in the [career] and [jobs] tags. Yeah, we got a *slight* tagging problem. =) Either way, you're absolutely right -- migrating these questions to Programmers en masse would be a mistake. At best, they should be individually considered.

Comment: I just voted to close most of them, there were a handful that were really nice and likely could find a good home on Programmers, like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214357/how-to-make-a-living-by-programming-from-home

Comment: The problem with that question is that it's old, and Programmers (like all 2.0 sites that I'm aware of) hates it when posts that predate it get migrated to it.